# Is this new user just that good?

Tags: discussion

Maxim DC, a newish user, posted half a dozen answers all at the same time. All of them have +1 vote. Except for the one on my question (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/119364/41345), because I downvoted it for being a poor answer.

Is this new user just that good that all of his answers were upvoted as soon as they were asked? (At least within 7 hours, which is when I saw it.) Or is my spidey sense tingling for a reason?

Comment: Respectfully, I wouldn't consider his answers to be "that good," they're mostly brief screenshots from the unreal editor with a sentence or two of brief explanation. People like easy answers and screenshots, it gets their attention, maybe even enough for a +1.

Comment: I just think there are carebears out there that like to 'give noobs a chance'. Fortunately, not too many users sabotage the site like this.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt my skepticism comes from his posts which aren't 7 hours old. Most of them have downvotes. Then all of a sudden, at the same time, a lot of upvoted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respectfully, the user in question *does not appear* to be particularly outstanding, especially in comparison to other users that have been around for as long. That is not to say they are particularly *bad*, but you can point to more opportunities for improvement than opportunities to learn from.

It is entirely likely that this user was simply flying under the radar of users that would normally enforce a bit more quality control; since the initial post, all but one answer has been lowered to *at least* a score of 0. Several answers have also been deleted.

With a score of less than 125, the user has asked one question with an average score of 0, and provided <del>13</del> answers with an average score of roughly <del>-0.25</del> -0.5. Without wanting to browse and vote on this users *entire* history, I have looked at their highest voted answer (without actually being accepted), and their lowest. In doing so, I felt obliged to cast one down vote, and refrained from further voting altogether.

The highest *had* a score of +2, but I felt it was posted with the intentions of a comment, and it doesn't seem to answer the question. This answer has since been removed, leaving only an *accepted answer* with a positive score. The lowest has a score of -6, and was a clear example of a codeing snippet without any explanation.

Answer (score 4):

There is no conclusive evidence of voting fraud on behalf of any party as of this writing.